# NumberFormatException while using sqlite in android

Tags: android, sqlite, numberformatexception

Can anyone please tell me what this logcat is demanding for?
Right now im trying to Create, Read, Update, Delete a string data in SQlite android,but im getting some NumberFormatException,how to solve this issue?

Suggestion please
Thanks for your precious time!..

**Logcat**

```
05-09 11:53:21.660: E/AndroidRuntime(854): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sqlite_sample/com.example.sqlite_sample.MainActivity}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse 'null' as integer
05-09 11:53:21.660: E/AndroidRuntime(854):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
05-09 11:53:21.660: E/AndroidRuntime(854):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
05-09 11:53:21.660: E/AndroidRuntime(854):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
05-09 11:53:21.660: E/AndroidRuntime(854):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
05-09 11:53:21.660: E/AndroidRuntime(854):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-09 11:53:21.660: E/AndroidRuntime(854):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-09 11:53:21.660: E/AndroidRuntime(854):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
05-09 11:53:21.660: E/AndroidRuntime(854):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-09 11:53:21.660: E/AndroidRuntime(854):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-09 11:53:21.660: E/AndroidRuntime(854):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
05-09 11:53:21.660: E/AndroidRuntime(854):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
05-09 11:53:21.660: E/AndroidRuntime(854):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-09 11:53:21.660: E/AndroidRuntime(854): Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse 'null' as integer
05-09 11:53:21.660: E/AndroidRuntime(854):  at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:356)
05-09 11:53:21.660: E/AndroidRuntime(854):  at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:332)
05-09 11:53:21.660: E/AndroidRuntime(854):  at com.example.sqlite_sample.DatabaseHandler.getAllContacts(DatabaseHandler.java:98)
05-09 11:53:21.660: E/AndroidRuntime(854):  at com.example.sqlite_sample.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:40)
05-09 11:53:21.660: E/AndroidRuntime(854):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
05-09 11:53:21.660: E/AndroidRuntime(854):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
05-09 11:53:21.660: E/AndroidRuntime(854):  ... 11 more
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{

String str_value = "Contact 1";

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);

    // Inserting Contacts
    Log.d("Insert: ", "Inserting ..");
    db.addContact(new Contact(str_value));
    db.addContact(new Contact("Contact 2"));
    db.addContact(new Contact("Contact 3"));

    // Reading all contacts
    Log.d(">>--Reading: ", "Reading all contacts..");
    List<Contact> contacts = db.getAllContacts();       

    for (Contact cn : contacts) {
        String log = "Id: "+cn.getID()+" ,Name: " + cn.getName() ;

    // Writing Contacts to log
    Log.d("Name: ", log);

    }
 }}
```

**Contact.java**

```
public class Contact {

//private variables
int _id;
String _name;

// Empty constructor
public Contact(){

}
// constructor
public Contact(int id, String name){
    this._id = id;
    this._name = name;
}

// constructor
public Contact(String name){
    this._name = name;
}
// getting ID
public int getID(){
    return this._id;
}

// setting id
public void setID(int id){
    this._id = id;
}

// getting name
public String getName(){
    return this._name;
}

// setting name
public void setName(String name){
    this._name = name;
}}
```

**DadabaseHandler.java**

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{

// All Static variables
// Database Version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "contactsManager";

// Contacts table name
private static final String TABLE_CONTACTS = "contacts";

// Contacts Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";

public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

// Creating Tables
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"+ ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
}

// Upgrading database
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Drop older table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CONTACTS);

    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);
}

// Adding new contact
void addContact(Contact contact) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.getName()); // Contact Name

    // Inserting Row
    db.insert(TABLE_CONTACTS, null, values);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection
}

// Getting single contact
Contact getContact(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_CONTACTS, new String[] { KEY_ID,
            KEY_NAME }, KEY_ID + "=?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();

    Contact contact = new Contact(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
            cursor.getString(1));
    // return contact
    return contact;
}

// Getting All Contacts
public List<Contact> getAllContacts() {
    List<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<Contact>();
    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Contact contact = new Contact();
            contact.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            contact.setName(cursor.getString(1));
            // Adding contact to list
            contactList.add(contact);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    return contactList;
}

// Updating single contact
public int updateContact(Contact contact) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.getName());

    // updating row
    return db.update(TABLE_CONTACTS, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getID()) });
}

// Deleting single contact
public void deleteContact(Contact contact) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_CONTACTS, KEY_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getID()) });
    db.close();
}

// Getting contacts Count
public int getContactsCount() {
    String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
    cursor.close();

    // return count
    return cursor.getCount();
}}
```

Comment: You have wrong sql syntax in creating table

Comment: @user974801 can you please tell me how to over come that issue?

Comment: @prabu unfortunately your table is not created so first try to correct your SQL command as per my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
 contact.setID(cursor.getInt(0));
```

instead of

```
 contact.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
```

in your `getContact(int id)` and `getAllContacts()` methods

also you go wrong over here

```
+ KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"+ ")"; // remove , after TEXT
```

correct your `SQL` Create Table command like

```
String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "("
        + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT"+ ")";
```

Comment: one more question.Can you please tell me how to override the data which is already available in sqlite database

Comment: @prabu i didn't get you?

Comment: i meant how to update my data in sqlite db, we will use update query right? my question is if we updated some existing data with some new data, will that existing data be still available on sqlite db?

Comment: @prabu you already update this older data with newer. what does update means? you change older with newer.dude!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52392/discussion-between-prabu-and-simple-plan)